# Cannot run single file generator in database project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to create a custom tool for .tt files in Visual Studio 2019. I have a .tt file in my database project.

When I try to set the custom tool in the properties window to my custom tool, I get the error *Property value is not valid.*, with details *Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.*

When I ignore that error and try to run the custom tool anyway, I get the error *Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID: %s.*

When I do this in a C# project, it works just fine. The built-in "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" custom tool works in the database project.

I want to create a custom tool for .tt files that works in whatever project type. How to do this?

Comment: Hi,check if [this document](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1023337/Custom-Tool-Single-File-Generator-for-Visual-Studi) can help you create  a custom tool.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Well, I have a custom tool that works in C# projects, just not in database projects. Also, the article you linked is for Visual Studio 2015, and it's not compatible with 2017/2019, as stated in the comments at the bottom of the page.

Comment: After l do a deep research, I find that this is an issue for database project and it seems that we cannot use custom tool in database project. See [this similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/703888c5-67c2-41cb-a37a-ab71793d5592/why-cant-i-run-a-custom-tool-in-an-sql-database-project?forum=ssdt). As a suggestion, you can report it to the [DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to reflect it.